# How to implement jQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I've followed the instructions I've found online and installed jQuery.ui complete package from the package manager. I've played around a lot with it and I cannot get it to pop up when I run it. The following is all the relevant code in my view in which I am needing the pop-up calendar.

The one simple line was just a test that was copied from the tutorial I followed just to see if that worked and not my editorfor.

```
@model Project.Models.Event
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
    </script>
</head>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>



<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Event</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })




    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>




    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" id="datepicker">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `EditorFor()` use `TextboxFor()` and fix your `htmlAttributes`

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.EventDate,
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

Which will render a `<input type="text">`. If the model property is `DateTime` then EditorFor produces `<input type="datetime">`. The datetime control conflicts with the plugin.

*The jQuery plugin may work with the datetime control but I have used other plugins that did not work and had to switch to a plain text input*.

Then you need to actually initialize the plugin. You have done so with a specific id `#datepicker` so that control works. You cannot duplicate id values so you've run into unspecified behavior -- The first element was registered but not the 2nd div.

Maybe use a class instead:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

Or choose unique ids.

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker();
$("#datepicker2").datepicker();
```

Comment: So with it being a DateTime.Date property, that interferes with is being EditorFor?

I followed your comment and it still won't work, it has also change the look of the text box and doesn't match the rest of the boxes. I've gotten this code when running it too: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Comment: And you never initialized it

Comment: I have not seen instructions in tutorials to initialize plugins, how do I do that? When you said that i have done so, did you not mean that i initialized it?

Comment: When you did `$("#datepicker"`).datepicker()` you initialized the input with `id="datepicker"` which is only a single element.

Comment: so when I did     
 <div class="col-md-10" id="datepicker"> it didn't initialize the textboxfor?

Comment: Duplicate id are not valid

Comment: so I would just need to change the id in that line? I thought you named things the same that worked together?

Comment: The id value must be unique on the document. Use the class attribute instead if you want to group things like that.

Comment: I have changed it to a class attribute like you suggested originally. I'm getting a little confused. is there easy to follow documentation online?

Comment: The jquery docs are as good as anything you'll find. And [unique ids are standard html](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute).